# What are the drawbacks to withdraw incomplete Schengen Visa application?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, applications

I am an Indian passport holder and recently applied for a tourist Schengen visa to French embassy (from Singapore). However, I am not able to provide complete documents for the application. I took my passport because I have to travel for work. If I am willing to withdraw my application, does withdrawing application during the visa process reduce chances of Schengen visa in future?